# Can IE interpret both JScript and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, javascript-engine

The [`window.setTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536753%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) reference for IE states that `setTimeout` has an optional third parameter defining the language.

The possible languages are JScript, VBScript and JavaScript.

I already know IE can parse VBScript but

**How does IE parse JavaScript differently from JScript?**

Personally I thought the dialect of EcmaScript that IE parsers and runs was called JScript.

[**Edit**]

As mentioned by people it appears that Microsoft labels their ES3 engine as "JScript" and their ES5 engine as "JavaScript". The ES5 engine is in IE9.

**Can we use their ES3 engine in IE9 by passing in `"JScript"` to `setTimeout` ?**

Comment: This question strikes me as being equivalent to asking whether Chrome can run 'V8 Scripts' but maybe I'm just confused by Microsoft's oddball terminology

Comment: @dtanders I interpret JavaScript as the Mozilla implementation of the ES engine. There might have been a chance that IE secretly has an extra interpreter hidden in it.

Comment: @dtanders: If you look at the MSDN link, it really does list "JScript" and "JavaScript" separately, and nowhere on the page does it say they're synonyms (which is just par for the course with MSDN documentation, in my experience; spotty doesn't half say it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Personally I thought the dialect of EcmaScript that IE parsers and runs was called JScript.

It is. The "JScript" and "JavaScript" values for the third parameter are just synonyms. I can't find a reference for it, but you can be quite certain IE doesn't have two separate interpreters lying around, one that has JScript-isms and one that doesn't.

And here's the proof: If you run this in IE9 ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/idazuh/2)):

HTML:

```
<input type='button' id='btnJScript' value='JScript'>
<input type='button' id='btnJavaScript' value='JavaScript'>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {

  document.getElementById('btnJScript').onclick = function() {
    testIt("JScript");
  };
  document.getElementById('btnJavaScript').onclick = function() {
    testIt("JavaScript");
  };

  function testIt(lang) {
    var s = "var a = [1, 2, ]; display(a.length);";
    display("Calling <code>setTimeout</code> with <code>'" +
            s + "', 0, '" + lang + "'</code>");
    setTimeout(s, 0,lang);
  }
};

function display(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = msg;
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

In both cases, you get the output "2" displayed by the eval'd `setTimeout` string. But in JScript, even the most recent version in IE8, that trailing comma would mean the array had three entries, not two. [Details on that here.](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/literal-improvement.html) Thus, IE9 is using its latest interpreter in both cases, *not* downshifting to "JScript" in some way if you pass "JScript" as the third parameter.

**Update**: And similarly (I just fired up my IE8 box), if you run this on IE8 you get "3" in both cases.

Comment: I'd be great if older versions happened to have a full interpreter of JavaScript lying around as well as JScript though. That'd be the best.

Comment: As far as IE is concerned, they're the same thing.

Comment: ps: this version (http://jsbin.com/idazuh/4) shows that EcmaScript is another synonym for Javascript, in the `setTimeout()` fn.  Also, it shows that FredScript is not a legal name for a language.

Answer (score 3):

From [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff729665%28v=VS.94%29.aspx), you can see that JScript is Microsoft's name for its implementation of ECMAScript 3, whereas JavaScript is its name for the implementation of ECMAScript 5 that appears in IE9.

Comment: Does mean that in IE9 I can run a snippet of JScript code by calling `window.setTimeout("var Run_AS_JScript = 42", 0, "JScript")` ?

Comment: This answer is not correct, or at the least, is misleading.   The MSDN page does not make the statement that the string "Javascript" refers to the IE9/ES5 implementation. It merely provides a link to the doc for Javascript-in-IE9, which is an implementation of ES5. It is more accurate to say: *in IE9, 'Javascript' refers to ES5.*  You can also use the string 'Javascript' in IE8, and it does not use the ES5 implementation.  That may be obvious to some, but it is worth clarifying.

Comment: Also: Though MS has not documented it, we can safely suppose that the string used in the language attr for `<script>` tags, as well as the string used in `setTimeout`, are ProgIds. They are strings in the Windows registry that refer to COM CLSIDs. This is the same thing you can use with `//E` on the cmd line for cscript.exe. JScript and Javascript point to exactly the same CLSID, the same object. IE9 probably has special handling of the term "Javascript", which looks up a different CLSID. None of this is documented, as far as I know. It is only what I surmise from observation and testing.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the best answer I could give, somebody else already did.

Well known, Mr. Resig in person: http://ejohn.org/blog/versions-of-javascript/

*snippet*

- IE 6-7 support JScript 5 (which is equivalent to ECMAScript 3, JavaScript 1.5)
- IE 8 supports JScript 6 (which is equivalent to ECMAScript 3, JavaScript 1.5 – more bug fixes over JScript 5)
- Firefox 1.0 supports JavaScript 1.5 (ECMAScript 3 equivalent)
- Firefox 1.5 supports JavaScript 1.6 (1.5 + Array Extras + E4X + misc.)
- Firefox 2.0 supports JavaScript 1.7 (1.6 + Generator + Iterators + let + misc.)
- Firefox 3.0 supports JavaScript 1.8 (1.7 + Generator Expressions + Expression Closures + misc.)
- The next version of Firefox will support JavaScript 1.9 (1.8 + To be determined)
- Opera supports a language that is equivalent to ECMAScript 3 + Getters and Setters + misc.
- Safari supports a language that is equivalent to ECMAScript 3 + Getters and Setters + misc.

I guess IE9's JScript engine (**Chakra**) comes as close as possible to "Javascript". However, it supports many features of ES5. See "[IE9 Javascript engine](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/18/the-new-javascript-engine-in-internet-explorer-9.aspx)". So we probably could extend the above list with

- IE9 supports JScript 9 (which is equivalent to ECMAScript 5, JavaScript 1.8.5)

Comment: That's completely unrelated to the question isn't it ;) To clarify. I know the difference between JScript and JavaScript. What are the differences between passing _those values_ into `setTimeout`

Comment: @Raynos: 'completely unrelated', are you kidding ?

Comment: @jAndy It's not unrelated but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @jAndy JScript 7 & 8 are JScript.NET. IE9 uses JScript 9.

Comment: @Raynos: didn't know that. can you give me the source of that please, pretty interested.

Comment: @jAndy [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript). I cant find a direct reference, but Microsoft does refer to versions of JScript.NET as JScript 7, 8 and 10. Logically I would assume that JScript 9 is indeed used in IE9

Answer (score 1):

You can safely think that JScript is the same as JavaScript and you won't bump into any problems.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript#Comparison_to_JavaScript

Comment: Why? Please state references.

Answer (score 1):

JScript and Javascript are the same things in IE. JScript was renamed to JavaScript in IE9 because of more standard (or better, more interoperable) implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The manual page you've referenced states that `sLanguage` is a parameter which can take the values `VBScript`, `JScript`, or `Javascript`.

It isn't that JScript is different from Javascript, it's just that both are valid names for the same language, they need to support both names.

JScript was Microsoft's name for their reverse-engineered clone of Javascript. The languages have now been merged by the standardisation work of the ECMA resulting in EcmaScript, although it is still generally referred to as Javascript.

But Microsoft needs to support both names because they want to retain compatiblity with old code written for ancient versions of IE which still uses the old JScript name.

Comment: I see. The correct name is "JavaScript". "JScript" is still in the list for backwards compatibility

Comment: @Raynos - yep, that's pretty much it.

Comment: To clarify a bit, "JavaScript" is a trademarked term owned by either AOL or Mozilla.